# How to create a sequence with several restrictions (freq, first order, second order)?

Tags: python-2.7, open-sesame

What i wanted:

A Sequence of 98 trials. The first 2 trials are random.
Afterwards i have 3 restrictions:

- same number of each stimulus (there are four stimuli, so each 24 times)
- 25% of all transitions are stimulus repetitions; 75% are alternations
- artificial grammar for 2nd order transitions

Here is the solution:

```
from random import shuffle
from random import choice
seq = [1, 2, 3, 4]
pool = seq *24
shuffle(pool)
result = [choice(seq), choice(seq)]
i=0
j=0
double=0
print result, i, double, j
#print pool


while True:

    while True:
        if len(result)==98:
            break
        if result[i]==1 or result[i]==3:
            if result[i+1]<3:
                for j in range(len(pool)+1):
                    if pool[-j]>2:  #second order restriction
                        if result[i+1] == pool[-j]:  #repetition restriction
                            double=double+1  #count doublings
                        result.append(pool[-j])  
                        pool.pop(-j) 
                        i=i+1
                        j=0
                        break
                    elif pool[-j]<3:  #go on searching in pool
                        if j==len(pool):  #no solution found in pool
                            pool = seq *24
                            shuffle(pool)
                            result = [choice(seq), choice(seq)]
                            print i
                            i=0
                            double=0
                            j=0
                        elif j!=len(pool):
                            j=j+1   
            elif result[i+1]>2:
                for j in range(len(pool)+1):
                    if pool[-j]<3:  #second order restriction
                        if result[i+1] == pool[-j]:  #repetition restriction
                            double=double+1  #count doublings
                        result.append(pool[-j])  
                        pool.pop(-j)
                        i=i+1
                        j=0
                        break
                    elif pool[-j]>2:  #go on searching in pool
                        if j==len(pool):  #no solution found in pool
                            pool = seq *24
                            shuffle(pool)
                            result = [choice(seq), choice(seq)]
                            print i
                            i=0
                            double=0
                            j=0
                        elif j!=len(pool):
                            j=j+1   
        elif result[i]==2 or result[i]==4:
            if result[i+1]<3:           
                for j in range(len(pool)+1):
                    if pool[-j]<3:  #second order restriction
                        if result[i+1] == pool[-j]:  #repetition restriction
                            double=double+1  #count doublings
                        result.append(pool[-j])  
                        pool.pop(-j) 
                        i=i+1
                        j=0
                        break
                    elif pool[-j]>2:  #go on searching in pool
                        if j==len(pool):  #no solution found in pool
                            pool = seq *24
                            shuffle(pool)
                            result = [choice(seq), choice(seq)]
                            print i
                            i=0
                            double=0
                            j=0
                        elif j!=len(pool):
                            j=j+1   
            elif result[i+1]>2:
                for j in range(len(pool)+1):
                    if pool[-j]>2:  #second order restriction
                        if result[i+1] == pool[-j]:  #repetition restriction
                            double=double+1  #count doublings
                        result.append(pool[-j])  
                        pool.pop(-j)
                        i=i+1
                        j=0
                        break
                    elif pool[-j]<3:  #go on searching in pool
                        if j==len(pool):  #no solution found in pool
                            pool = seq *24
                            shuffle(pool)
                            result = [choice(seq), choice(seq)]
                            print i
                            i=0
                            double=0
                            j=0
                        elif j!=len(pool):
                            j=j+1   

            #print result, len(result), i, double, j
            #print pool

    if double==24:
        break
    else:
        pool = seq *24
        shuffle(pool)
        result = [choice(seq), choice(seq)]
        print i, j
        i=0
        double=0
        j=0

print result, len(result), double
```

Comment: Can you be more specific about what "my computer doesn't make it" means?  Do you get a syntax error, does the script fail to terminate?

Comment: The program does not work anymore. I have to shut it down manually. I am using OpenSesame. Maybe the code is endless?

Comment: I found the solution on my own: